# JavaScript: script to download via AJAX and load chart just doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>

    var highchartsOptions = {
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons:{
                contextButton:{
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
                  enabled: false
            },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        colors: ['#2b908f', '#f7a35c', '#434348', '#8085e9', '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', '#91e8e1']
    };



function showTopPickrate(data) {

    $('#containerTopPickrate').highcharts({
            chart: highchartsOptions.chart,
            title: highchartsOptions.title,
            credits: highchartsOptions.credits,
            exporting: highchartsOptions.exporting,
            tooltip: highchartsOptions.tooltip,
            plotOptions: highchartsOptions.plotOptions,
            colors: highchartsOptions.colors,
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    data[0]._id.championId,
                    data[2]._id.championId,
                    data[3]._id.championId,
                    data[4]._id.championId,
                    data[5]._id.championId,
                    data[6]._id.championId,
                    data[7]._id.championId,
                    data[8]._id.championId,
                    data[9]._id.championId,
                    data[10]._id.championId
                ],
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Popularity',
                data: [ floor(data[0].value.pickRate*100) , 
                       floor(data[1].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[2].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[3].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[4].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[5].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[6].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[7].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[8].value.pickRate*100), 
                       floor(data[9].value.pickRate*100)]

            }, {
                name: 'Win Rate',
                data: [ floor(data[0].value.winRate*100) , 
                       floor(data[1].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[2].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[3].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[4].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[5].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[6].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[7].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[8].value.winRate*100), 
                       floor(data[9].value.winRate*100)]

            }]
        });

}




function loadTopPickrate(day){

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:2000/mapReduce/getMapReduceResultsTopPickRate?day="day,
      type: "get",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
            alert("got it"); // debug
            showTopPickrate(data);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("error");
      }  
    }); 

}

$(function() {
    loadTopPickrate("all");
});

</script>
```

I'm new to front end web dev but I've done a lot of javascript in the past, yet I really dont know why this piece of code, I'm wasting lots of time with this and I need this done soon.

It just wont execute at all, but I cant see the syntax errors or how its wrong (its mostly based on SO answers since I dont know jQuery), I need help with declaring and using functions with jQuery, or if its the AJAX call that is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you built the url is wrong

```
url: "http://localhost:2000/mapReduce/getMapReduceResultsTopPickRate?day="day,
```

needs to be

```
url: "http://localhost:2000/mapReduce/getMapReduceResultsTopPickRate?day=" + day,
```

better yet to use data

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:2000/mapReduce/getMapReduceResultsTopPickRate",
  data : {
      day : day
  },
  type: "get",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
        alert("got it"); // debug
        showTopPickrate(data);
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("error");
  }  
});
```

Comment: How could I not see that, thank you mate.

Though now I'm getting the error alert from the AJAX code, and the URL works through the browser...

Comment: So now change the error code so you know what the message is `error:function(){ console.error(arguments); }`

Comment: Well, I got this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:2000/mapReduce/getMapReduceResultsTopPickRate?day=all. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access`

I'm googling it right now, but, do you know of a quick fix? Accepting your answer regardless, since you solved the original problem, thank you

Comment: You are hitting a different port/ url which is a violation of the Same Origin Policy. You should be running off localhost and not your drive.

Comment: I set the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to a wildcard in the backend and for some reason it gets the data now. The graph wont show though. I'm sorry to keep annoying you with this but since you seem to have experience, so you see any obvious mistake with the showTopPickrate(data) function? I tried surrounding its content with `$(function () { });`, still no effect. Also fixed the typo in the categories section. Got the chart from http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

Comment: nevermind, it works now! for anyone wondering it was a typo in the container id